# Child divs height isn't the same as parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a 7 `divs` wrapped in 3 `divs`. All but the first `div` are set to `width: 0`, and they are all set to `inline-block`. The most outer `div` has a set height of `166px`.

So it comes out, the only child (7) `divs` you see, is the first. The problem is, the third wrapper (`.wrapperLongInner`), has a larger height than its grandparents `div`. `.wrapperLongInner's` height is calculated as if the 7 `divs` are layed out one under each other, even though they they are side-by-side due to `flex`.

How can I get `.wrapperLongInner` to have the same height as its parent parent by default?

#### JSFiddle

```css
.wrapperShortOuter {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.wrapperLongInner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullWrapper" style="height: 166px; width: 536px;">
  <div class="wrapperShortOuter">
    <div class="wrapperLongInner" style="width: 1072px;">
      <div class="content" style="width: 536px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
      <div class="content">quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</div>
      <div class="content">Tin voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
      <div class="content">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium</div>
      <div class="content">doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem</div>
      <div class="content">quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</div>
      <div class="content">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
        ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I ask why you need a `wrapperShortOuter`? If `wrapperLongInner` is the only child, having it as a parent seems unnecessary. You could even set `overflow: hidden;` to `wrapperLongInner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to give **height:100%** in the **.wrapperLongInner** class like this :-

```
.wrapperLongInner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Note** :- In **internet explorer** there is a **chaining mechanism** which they use if height:100% is given. So, you will have to give height:100% to all the divs in the chain till a parent div with fixed height ( not in percentage ) comes. If the chain breaks, no height will be applied to the div.
For I.E. you need to do something like this along with the above code:-

```
.wrapperShortOuter {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can refer the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aalind/etnkj0Lp/3/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided html, it seems that you can just give its parent (`.wrapperShortOuter`) `height: 100%`, which will in turn take the height of its "grandparent":

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etnkj0Lp/1/)

```
.wrapperShortOuter {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set height for parent and grandparent divs. Remove `width:0;` from content div and add `float:left` instead

```
.wrapperShortOuter{
height:100%;
}
.wrapperLongInner{
height:100%
}
.content{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `height: inherit;` on CSS class `.wrapperShortOuter`.

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value
>   from its parent element.

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/etnkj0Lp/2/

```
.wrapperShortOuter {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: clean css solution