# How to make divs same height?

Tags: html, css

I have one parent-div which contains three `divs` and I would like to make them same height but it is not working. The first and third `div` contains each an image. The second `div` contains three `divs` with content.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x318">
    </div>

    <div class="column2">
        <div class="row1">
            <div class="text">UNIKE GUSTAVIANSKE STILMØBLER.</div>
            <div class="text">VI SELGER HÅNDVERK ETTER 1700-</div>
            <div class="text">OG 1800-TALLS TRADISJONER.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row2"></div> 
        <div class="row3">
            <div class="text">
                Åpningstider:<br>
                Man - Fre 11 -17     Lør 11- 15
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="column3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x318">
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.container` has the css-rule `display:flex;`. When I apply this also to `.column1`, `.column2` and `.column3`, the layout breaks.

I am trying to achieve that the images height increase and decrease depended to `.column2`. Unfortunately, I have not the possibility to change the HTML or use JS.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/t6bkgams/1/) you can see a JS-Fiddle. I have commented out the CSS-rules.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031962/child-divs-height-isnt-the-same-as-parent-div/39032193#39032193). Please check my answer [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39032193/6386166). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: the heights of the three `flexbox` children are equal in your code above (because `align-items: stretch` is the default... try adjusting the images, see [a reference here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289576/css-image-resize-issue/39289947#39289947)

Comment: Your code is correct, see here with backgroundColor: https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/18mzofbs/15/ or you want to stretch their images inside or centered vertical?

Comment: @pleinx Yes, I would like them to stretch out so that they cover the space. But they should keep aspect ratio. It is okay if they get hidden under the second column.

Comment: @dahlsdata-tahira did you try using the `object-fit: cover;` css rule I showed in my answer below. Based on this comment and your question it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you mention that you apply `display:flex` to `.column1`, `.column2` and `.column3`.

Instead just apply this to `.column1` and `.column3` and leave `.column2` as `display:block`.

This should resolve your problem (works in your JS-Fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply a height and max-width to the images. They will distort to fit into the space and make your images look weird. If you choose images that are this dimensions, they will look better.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.container img{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.row1 .text {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.row2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #e4e8eb;
}
.row3 {
  background-color: #c7cacf;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.row3 .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x318">
  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="text">
        UNIKE GUSTAVIANSKE STILMØBLER.</div>
      <div class="text">VI SELGER HÅNDVERK ETTER 1700-</div>
      <div class="text">OG 1800-TALLS TRADISJONER.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <div class="row3">
      <div class="text">Åpningstider:
        <br>Man - Fre 11 -17 Lør 11- 15</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x318">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding properly you can add this to your styles:

```
img { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Your columns are already filling to the parent height. Using the above css styles the images in this will fill the parent div height and basically overflow the width. If you do something else like set height of the images to 100% it will distort the image.

Here is a similar question with same (but more detailed) answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967278/3366016

Answer (score 0):

you can add this lines for row css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the height and width of image tag.Just add width:100% and height 100% for image tag.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.container img{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.row1 .text {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.row2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #e4e8eb;
}
.row3 {
  background-color: #c7cacf;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.row3 .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.imgsize{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x318" class="imgsize">
  </div>

  <div class="column2">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="text">
        UNIKE GUSTAVIANSKE STILMØBLER.</div>
      <div class="text">VI SELGER HÅNDVERK ETTER 1700-</div>
      <div class="text">OG 1800-TALLS TRADISJONER.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <div class="row3">
      <div class="text">Åpningstider:
        <br>Man - Fre 11 -17 Lør 11- 15</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x318" class="imgsize">
  </div>
</div>
```